# How to wait until a file is checked in in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, flow, power-automate

I'm in the process of migrating my 2010 Designer Workflows to Power Automate. In the past we've had issues when an InfoPath form has been edited and saved but not yet checked in, the SPD workflow tries to run against that file, and throws an error. Two questions: is this still an issue with Power Automate Flows, and if so, how can you tell Power Automate to wait until the file is checked in? I know how to test IF the file is checked in, but how would you construct the Wait Until loop? (Yes, yes, I know- get rid of InfoPath... but that's not going to happen until after the workflows are migrated - we have about 500 to rebuild, and three months to do it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Schedule - Recurrence** trigger action to check the file on a schedule.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks

Comment: That won't work. What happens is that a user saves the InfoPath form, then the workflow runs to see if the process status of the file has changed. If the file was "New" and now is "In First Review", then the permissions to the file get updated and an email gets sent to the first reviewer. If it was "In First Review" and now is "In Second Review",  the permissions need updated again and the second reviewer notified, and so on. In the past, the check-in has not always happened before the workflow ran, so the permissions update would fail.